# Evenly Space UIViews of equal sizes in superview using Auto Layout in iOS 6

Tags: uiview, ios6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am in a need of having the series of buttons to be evenly placed in superview Horizontally using Auto Layout.
Here, I want to keep the sizes of the subviews same, only the center of the subviews will be placed in such a way that there is equal number of space between them.

Note: I dont want to set the Size of the superview, I want every thing to be Auto Layout-ed.

Please Help,
I am stuck !!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create as many `UIView`'s as you have buttons, and center the buttons inside the views, the views can be aligned back to back, using this code:

```
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view1][view2][view3]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
```

Make sure you first remove existing constraints from the superview using:

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
```

and in the viewDidLoad turn off auto resizing conversion:

```
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply !! but here I dont want the views to be placed one after the other (leading-trailing) but should be spaced in such a way that they appear evenly distributed along the width with common gap between them.

Comment: Yes, that's why you center the buttons inside the views, that way they are evenly distributed. The views are back to back, and the buttons are centered inside them.

Comment: Ya I was doing the same way as you suggested as a work around.

Comment: But I guess there has to be some way of achieving it without the extra views, in Auto Layout environment.

Comment: But this is going to use a standard margins between views, right? How would you make it custom?