# How to distribute space equally between multiple buttons?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, xcode6

I have four buttons inside a view container. I want to have the space between the buttons automatically resized equally depending on the device's screen size.

The view container is constrained as follows:

- Horizontal and Vertical to Superview
- Equal With to Superview
- Leading and Trailing Space to Superview

Then I constrained each button with:

- Equal With and Height
- Vertical Space to the view container.

After this point whatever combination I try I can't get the buttons have equal space between them. I tried giving them Horizontal Spacing Constrain but that didn't do the trick. Attached is the effect I would like to create. Can anyone please explain how to accomplish this?

[image: Equally distribute space]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706444/simplest-way-to-evenly-distribute-uibuttons-horizontally-across-width-of-view-co

Answer (score 0):

Place empty `UIViews` between the buttons and give them the following constraints:

- Leading and trailing space to the adjacent buttons to 0
- Equal widths
- Width >= 0
- Some height constraint

That should do the trick

Comment: Apple describes it at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html search for "Creating Equal Spacing Between Views"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create such `UIButtons` with equally divided `width` is as follows:

Create 6 `UIButtons` like this:

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[button1 setTitle:@"Btn1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

... do that 6 times for 6 buttons, however you like then add them to the view:

```
[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
[self.view addSubview:button3];
[self.view addSubview:button4];
[self.view addSubview:button5];
[self.view addSubview:button6];
```

Fix one button to the bottom of your `UIView`:

Then,

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

Then tell all the buttons to be equal width and spread out equally across the width:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[button1][button2(==button1)][button3(==button1)][button4(==button1)][button5(==button1)][button6(==button1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:views]];
```

All the best...

Comment: I have changed the attribute to NSLayoutAttributeTop, now u can check the code, u ll be able to see all the buttons at the top of the UIView

Comment: This is not exactly what he asked. That way the buttons will take up all the horizontal space, right? there won't be any blank space between each button.